# Best approximations to energy levels of Helium Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics, computational-physics, hamiltonian

I'd like to know the first few energy levels of the helium Hamiltonian, not the physical atom itself, only the Hamiltonian.

I'm looking for patterns in the math, not patterns in the physics, so I don't want experimentally measured values.

I'd prefer using a Hamiltonian without a nuclear mass term, to simplify the equation and try to produce the simplest patterns in the eigenvalue spectrum.  So, preferably, a Hamiltonian with just kinetic energy and all three Coulomb force interactions.  No relativity, no magnetic interactions, with or without nuclear mass.

Or, preferably, all combinations of the above: the first ten or twenty eigenvalues in the spectrum, for the helium Hamiltonian, for various combinations of various terms (nuclear mass, magnetic effects, relativity) included or ignored.

Are these energy levels known?

What would be the best program to compute such a list (or table)?

Comment: For software options, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software. If you want more details, first define "best".

Comment: One possibility for the energy levels are given here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131191/why-does-exchange-integral-1s2p-not-vanish-for-helium-excited-state/162841#162841